# angularjs service for badge count

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I want add a badge to my cart whenever a product is added or deleted from cart.I am trying to use services but no luck...

This is my service

```
.factory('sharedCounterService', [function(){

     var obj={};

     obj.count=0;


     obj.addToCartcount=function(){
         obj.count+=1;
         console.log("COUNT" +obj.count);
     };

     obj.removeFromCartcount=function(){
         obj.count-=1; 
         console.log("COUNT" +obj.count);
     };

     return obj;
}]);
```

Controller

```
.controller('productCtrl', function($scope,$http,sharedCartService,sharedFilterService,sharedCounterService) {
    $scope.addToCart = function(id,image,name,price){  

        $scope.count=sharedCounterService.addToCartcount;     

        console.log("COUNT" +sharedCounterService.count);

        cart.add(id,image,name,price,1);    
    };
})

.controller('cartCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope,sharedCartService,$ionicPopup,$state,$http,sharedCounterService) {

    $scope.count=sharedCounterService.removeFromCartcount;     

    console.log("COUNT" +sharedCounterService.count);
})         
.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope,sharedCartService,sharedCounterService) {

     $scope.count=sharedCounterService;

     console.log("COUNT" +sharedCounterService.count);
 });
```

Html

```
<a  href="#" class="button  button-icon ion-android-cart" ><span class="badge badge-assertive">{{count}}</span>
```

When i console it only counter is increasing cart value is 0

Comment: In your `factory` you return the `obj` variable, so you should attach the methods to that object and not to `obj1` that is never defined.

Comment: @user3698911 Protip: include a working snippet or _at least_ properly indent your code to improve your chances of a speedy response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this line:

```
$scope.count = sharedCounterService.addToCartcount;
```

you assign the current value of `addToCartcount` to `$scope.count`, but any time this line executes:

```
obj.count += 1;
```

or this line:

```
obj.count -= 1;
```

`obj.count` is overwritten with a new value, but `$scope.count` continues referring to its original value.

To fix this, put the whole counter object on your scope:

```
$scope.cartCounter = sharedCounterService;
```

And reference the count in your view:

```
<a href="#" class="button  button-icon ion-android-cart">
  <span class="badge badge-assertive">{{cartCounter.count}}</span>
</a>
```

Comment: I tried this one now the badge value is 0 it is not increasing when i add products to cart...

Comment: @user3698911 Please provide us with an [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), preferably in the form of a stack snippet, that we can modify to show it working.